# When I use a .jar file to store a set of program components, it won't run

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have a set of documents(java, class, html) that I put into a .jar file named calc.jar with:

```
jar cmf MANIFEST.MF calc.jar calc.java calc.class calc.html
```

It creates an "executable jar" file in my folder, but it does nothing when I open it. Then I run the file in the cmd with the following:

```
jar -jar calc.jar
```

After that, it reads:

```
Illegal option: j
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0PMe] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] f
iles ...
Options:
-c  create new archive
-t  list table of contents for archive
-x  extract named (or all) files from archive
-u  update existing archive
-v  generate verbose output on standard output
-f  specify archive file name
-m  include manifest information from specified manifest file
-n  perform Pack200 normalization after creating a new archive
-e  specify application entry point for stand-alone application
    bundled into an executable jar file
-0  store only; use no ZIP compression
-P  preserve leading '/' (absolute path) and ".." (parent directory) compone
nts from file names
-M  do not create a manifest file for the entries
-i  generate index information for the specified jar files
-C  change to the specified directory and include the following file
If any file is a directory then it is processed recursively.
The manifest file name, the archive file name and the entry point name are
specified in the same order as the 'm', 'f' and 'e' flags.

Example 1: to archive two class files into an archive called classes.jar:
   jar cvf classes.jar Foo.class Bar.class
Example 2: use an existing manifest file 'mymanifest' and archive all the
       files in the foo/ directory into 'classes.jar':
   jar cvfm classes.jar mymanifest -C foo/ .
```

What's going on?!?

EDIT: My manifest file reads:

```
Manifest-version: 1.0
Main-Class: calc
```

Using `java -jar calc.jar` brings this up:

```
Error: Main method not found in class calc, please define the main method
```

However, my .java file contains the main method.

Comment: To run it via cmd, I believe you want to use `java -jar` instead of `jar -jar`.

Comment: You'd need to show us the contents of the manifest (is main class set?) and at least the declaration of your calc class (which you should probably capitalize anyway) because unless it's in the default package, you still won't end up with a properly working 'executable' jar

Comment: Post your calc.java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line syntax is off. You are attempting to execute the .jar file with the jar command, which is intended to package the files only.

Try something like this:

java -jar calc.jar calc

The java command with -jar delimeter indicates that you want to execute a jar file.

Answer (score -1):

The output clearly says

```
-j
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0PMe] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] f
iles ...
```

-j not supported, As NESPowerGlove rightly pointed out.

Basically you are using the jar command in wrong way. Kindly read the man page or usage carefully and try again.